# Importing a created module and printing it

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, module, return-value, python-import

I created a module named smethod.py, which includes this code: (first def to make mixed cased letters lowercase and second to capitalize)

```
def LWR():
    result=""
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        value = ord(s[i])
        if value>64 and value<91:
            result+=chr(value+32)
        else:
            result+=chr(value)
    s=result
    print(s)
    return


def TTL():
    ssplit = s.split()
    small_a = ord("a") 
    small_z = ord("z")

    cap_a = ord("A")   

    delta = small_a - cap_a

    for z in ssplit :  
        if small_a <= ord(z[0]) <= small_z:
            l = chr(ord(z[0])-delta)
            new = l + z[1:]            
            print(new, end=" ") 
        else:
            print(s)
    return
```

Then I opened a new file and did this:

```
import smethod
s = input("Enter your string")
print("The lowercase version is:" ,smethod.LWR)
print("Title version is: ",smethod.TTL)

============= RESTART: /Users/ezgibahadir/Documents/smethod2.py =============
enter your stringezgi bahadır
The lowercase version is: <function LWR at 0x1111b28c0>
Title version is:  <function TTL at 0x1111413b0>
```

What is the reason?

Comment: You're not calling either of those functions. Also neither of them take any arguments, so it's unclear how you expect the input to get into them. I'd recommend reading e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that could be improved.

- You said you called the file `method.py`, so why are you importing `smethod`?
- Your functions LWR and TTL don't take any arguments. Both of them refer to `s`, where does that `s` come from?
- Even if they did work, you don't call them. You need to do `method.LWR()`.
- You've declared that this is Python3, but you're using the print function like Python2.

Some other issues:

- Giving function names as 3-letter capital codes is not the python way. Call them `to_lower` and `to_upper` or something instead.
- Given that this process is super common, both of these functions are provided in the standard library, you don't even need separate functions.

You could just do:

```
import smethod
s = input("Enter your string")
print(f"The lowercase version is: {s.lower()}")
print(f"Title version is: {s.upper()}")
```

---

In order to recreate the full function with `chr` and `ord`, you should be declaring something like:

```
def to_lower(s):
    # code here
    return result
```

And then to call it:

```
s = 'Hello World!'
print(to_lower(s))
```

Comment: I wrote method.py by mistake. actually it is smethod.py. I know that I could use s.lower, etc. but chr and ord are what I have to use as my instructor said in my university. That's why. @blueteeth

Comment: I've added a section pointing the way for how to declare and use the full function.

Comment: @Ch138 Please mark the post as solved if you have a solution, or provide more information if you don't.